# New Users page - loss of highlighting own name

Tags: feature-request

The latest change to the Users page has lost the highlighting of yourself at the top that was recently added.

I found that listing quite interesting and would like it back.

This was on askdifferent and Super user From @ChrisF comment I think that that the default you get from choosing the users button has changed on my and I don't think I have changed anything.

Comment: Which users page? http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow does have me highlighted at the top, but http://stackoverflow.com/users never has.

Comment: can you be more specific?